# Retrieve user and password from Datatable for Login

Tags: java, html, mysql, netbeans-7

I am using Netbeans. I have created user and password to datatable. I have problems troubleshooting for my Login and password to access my another jsp file. It shows me HTTP Status 404 - Not Found. What is the problem?

The following is my `logincheck.jsp` code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ page language="Java" import="java.sql.*" %>  
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body> 

<%
String username = request.getParameter("username");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
String userType = request.getParameter("usertype");

String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.localDriver";
String dbURL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Parts ";

String dbuser = "user";
String dbpassword = "password";

Connection theConnection = null;
PreparedStatement theStatement = null;

try {

    Class.forName(driver);

    theConnection=DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,dbuser,dbpassword);

    theStatement = theConnection.prepareStatement("select * from USERS");

    theStatement.setString(1,request.getParameter("username"));
    theStatement.setString(2,request.getParameter("password"));

    ResultSet theResult = theStatement.executeQuery();

     if(theResult.next())
         System.out.println("welcome.jsp");
     else
         System.out.println("Failed");
}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception occured! "+e.getMessage()+" "+e.getStackTrace());
}  
%>
</body>
```

Comment: Where does the 404 error occur?

Comment: it show status on HTTP 404 - Not Found type Status report messageNot Found descriptionThe requested resource is not available. What should i do?

Comment: I mean on which line does the error occur?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be error...

```
  theStatement = theConnection.prepareStatement("select * from USERS");
```

should be like this..

```
 theStatement = theConnection.prepareStatement("select * from USERS where Username=? and Password=?)

theStatement.setString(1,username);
theStatement.setString(2,password);
..
..
```

Let me know if this works....

Comment: @Drew, 404 means `Page not found on server`

Comment: @Drew, you may be right. It's possible that it has got nothing to do with Query, because if there is even one record in `Users` table then `theResult.next()` will succeed and call welcome.jsp.


@Poh Chang Chien, you should check the URL when welcome,jsp is hit. It's definitely the path problem. Your welcome.jsp should be on the root level. If not, then you need to specify complete path starting from root level. For example: `http://yoursite.com/path_to_welcome_jsp/welcome.jsp`

Comment: Thanks. :) theStatement = theConnection.prepareStatement("select * from USERS where Username= login and Password=password) . it's error for this statement

Comment: it's show unclosed string literal on the above statement.

Comment: it show status on HTTP 404 - Not Found  type Status report

messageNot Found

descriptionThe requested resource is not available. What should i do?

Comment: Check my comment for the absolute path

Answer (score 0):

get a require user and password from database by result set.

```
String user=usertx.getText();
    char[] password=pswdtx.getPassword();
    String pswd=String.valueOf(password);   \\here is important to put a char password in string.`
```

1- we call the require user and his password by:
`Resultset rs= stmt.excuteQuery("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE NAME='"+user+"' AND PASSWORD='"+pswd+"'");`
   this code will get only the row of selected user and his information on row and set it in (rs).`

2- code of rs.next():

```
while(rs.next()){
        rsuser=rs.getString("NAME");         //get user and set it in rsuser.
        rspswd=rs.getString("PASSWORD");}    //get password and set it in rspswd.
        if ((user.equals(rsuser)) && (pswd.equals(rspswd))){  //the equevlant statment.
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and Password exist");}
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Check Username and Password ");}
        }
```

here is whole of code:

```
private void submitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    try {
        String user=usertx.getText();
        char[] password=pswdtx.getPassword();
        String pswd=String.valueOf(password);

        String rsuser=null;
        String rspswd=null;
        String Q="SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE NAME='"+user+"' AND PASSWORD='"+pswd+"'";
        rs=stmt.executeQuery(Q);

        while(rs.next()){
        rsuser=rs.getString("NAME");
        rspswd=rs.getString("PASSWORD");}
        if ((user.equals(rsuser)) && (pswd.equals(rspswd))){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and Password exist");}
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Check Username and Password ");}
        } 
    catch (SQLException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}`

}
```